# Compile openjdk to Android

Tags: java, android, cross-compiling

It is possible to compile openjdk (11 or higher) to android system. If possible, how can I do it? I am trying to use android ndk, but it did not help. I know this is possible, because Jvdroid developer using JDK 11 version.

Comment: It is unclear what you are talking about. Are you talking about compiling OpenJDK? Or  compiling a Java application that uses OpenJDK APIs?  And do you want to run that application on Android?

Comment: I am talking about compiling openjdk

Comment: The instructions are here: https://openjdk.java.net/projects/mobile/android.html

Comment: It doesn't work for me(

Comment: Are you building the correct version?  http://hg.openjdk.java.net/mobile/dev  ?